# ワードプレスで更新日が90日以内の記事を取得

Tags: php, wordpress

**現状のコード**

```php
array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'after' => date('Y/m/d 0:0:0', strtotime('-3 month')),
);
```

---

このようにしていたのですが、これだと３ヶ月以上経っている記事のみ取得している？と気づきまして、
更新日が９０日以内の記事のみを取得する場合にはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

`date_query`を使ってできました。

```php
'date_query'=>array(
    array( 
        'column'=>'post_modified',
        'inclusive'=>true,
        'after'=> date('Y/m/d 0:0:0', strtotime('-3 month')),
    ),
),
```